# Adjusting the signature between "Sincerely and Name"

Tags: templates, letters, cv

[image]

I want to placing the signature between "Sincerely and Name". Using the latex  commands French Cursive: {\cursive\setul{0.1ex}{}\ul{~~Mickly~~}}

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter} % Default font size of the document, change to 10pt to fit more text

\usepackage{newcent} % Default font is the New Century Schoolbook PostScript font
\usepackage{soul}% for the underlining
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}% just to set the samples further apart

\usepackage{emerald}% for 1-4
\usepackage{frcursive}% for 5
\usepackage{inslrmin}% for 6

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{helvet} % Uncomment this (while commenting the above line) to use the Helvetica font

% Margins
\topmargin=-1in % Moves the top of the document 1 inch above the default
\textheight=8.5in % Total height of the text on the page before text goes on to the next page, this can be increased in a longer letter
\oddsidemargin=-10pt % Position of the left margin, can be negative or positive if you want more or less room
\textwidth=6.5in % Total width of the text, increase this if the left margin was decreased and vice-versa

\let\raggedleft\raggedright % Pushes the date (at the top) to the left, comment this line to have the date on the right

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{letter}{Professor \\
Institut \\
University\\
City, Country 123456}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME & ADDRESS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\large\bf Mick Fre \\ % Your name
\vspace{20pt}
\hrule height 1pt % If you would like a horizontal line separating the name from the address, uncomment the line to the left of this text
Street \\ City, Country 123456 \\ 111-333-111 % Your address and phone number
\end{center}


\signature{Name} % Your name for the signature at the bottom

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\opening{Respected Professor:}

JD: {\ECFJD\setul{0.1ex}{}\ul{~~Mickly~~}}

Skeetch: {\ECFSkeetch\setul{0.1ex}{}\ul{~~Mickly~~}}

Teen Spirit: {\ECFTeenSpirit\setul{-0.1ex}{0.3pt}\ul{~~Mickly~~}}

Tall Paul: {\ECFTallPaul\setul{0.15ex}{}\ul{~~Mickly~~}}

French Cursive: {\cursive\setul{0.1ex}{}\ul{~~Mickly~~}}

Insular Minuscule: {\iminfamily\setul{0.1ex}{}\ul{~~Mickly~~}}

\closing{Sincerely yours,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner yea but i want to merge the two code

Comment: @MickyK: The only addition would be to insert `\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{mysignature}` in your code (and `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble). Of course, you have to go through the process of creating the signature first. That's included in the linked duplicate.

Comment: I think it is not possible to adjust the signature b/w Sincerely and Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `letter` class is not easy to manipulate. You should steer clear from modifications if you're not familiar on how to manage it.

Below is a replication of your setup using the default `article` class instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}% just to set the samples further apart
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\Large\bfseries\centering

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME & ADDRESS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mick Fre

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

Street

City, County 123456

111-333-111

\bigskip

\normalsize\mdseries\raggedright

\today

\bigskip

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Professor

Institut

University

City, Country 123456

\bigskip

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Respected Professor:

JD: \rule[-.4pt]{10em}{.4pt}

Skeetch: \rule[-.4pt]{10em}{.4pt}

Teen Spirit: \rule[-.4pt]{10em}{.4pt}

Tall Paul: \rule[-.4pt]{10em}{.4pt}

French Cursive: \rule[-.4pt]{10em}{.4pt}

Insular Minuscule: \rule[-.4pt]{10em}{.4pt}

Sincerely yours,

\bigskip

\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{signature}

Name% Your name for the signature at the bottom

\end{document}
```

---

If you insist on using the `letter` class, you can insert the signature using

```
\signature{\includegraphics[height=2\normalbaselineskip]{signature} \\ Name}
```

Comment: This is not the solution of above Question

Comment: @MickyK: Could you elaborate? There is, as you requested, a "signature between 'Sincerely and Name'"...

Comment: Now check the above picture you will find the latex commands, which i want to adjust between sincerely and name

Comment: @MickyK: Have you tried `\signature{\iminfamily\setul{0.1ex}{}\ul{~~Mickly~~} \\ Name}`, similar to what I suggest at the end of my answer?

Comment: How we adjust the spacing b/w signature and sincerely

Comment: @MickyK: The `\closing` and `\signature` is both set with a call to `\closing`, and the gap between the two is set to `6\medskipamount` (about 46pt). You can change this amount to suit your needs by adding `\usepackage{etoolbox} \patchcmd{\closing}{6\medskipamount}{\medskipamount}{}{}` to your preamble. The patch reduced the inserted space to just `\medskipamount`.